# Algorithm for checking if board is connected

Tags: algorithm, love2d

I am creating a snake AI and when it runs it often traps itself, so I would like to check if the whole board is connected at all times and AI will move accordingly. I can't come up with a good and short algorithm for that. I am using an A* pathfinding algorithm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am using an A* pathfinding algorithm."* exactly? Does your implementation of A* work? Does it not work? Are you disappointed in the results for some reason? Why? It sounds like A* should indeed give an answer to the question: is there a path from the serpent's head to the sides of the arena?

Comment: Everything is working, but as the snake gets longer it sometimes traps itself and can’t find a path. I am thinking about checking if every spot on the board is connected but can’t find a way to program it. I tried checking if every spot has at least 2 connections but that failed as sometimes there is a square that is isolated from the board by the tail.

Comment: To check if each point is connected, you can use a filling algorithm from computer-graphics. Start filling the plane at a random empty point and at the end check if there is an empty point left not filled if so is was not connected to the starting point.